# Is it possible to find the oldest unanswered questions in my tags?

Tags: feature-request, unanswered-questions, sorting

I would like to find the oldest questions that remain unanswered in my areas of expertise.

In the "Unanswered" tab, it seems to me like the most logical sort order for questions is oldest-first.

I think it should at least be an option.

In addition, if this list were filterable by my "interesting" tags, I think I could be quite a bit more effective at finding and answering questions.

Comment: Please feel free to click the little checkmark to "accept" this answer, if it was satisfactory for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can search for questions with no answers with the search tag `answers:0`. So to search for unanswered question in your favourite tag `asp.net-mvc`, enter `[asp.net-mvc] answers:0`, i.e.: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[asp.net-mvc]+answers%3A0.

Unfortunately it is not possible to search for all your favourite tags at once other than by manually constructing a gigantic url (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc%20or%20sql-server). This works for the "unanswered" category as well, e.g [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/unanswered/asp.net-mvc%20or%20sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/unanswered/asp.net-mvc%20or%20sql-erver).

Comment: +1: Awesome.  However, I still think that Oldest should be the default sort order.

Comment: I believe the default order is whatever you used last time, so if you prefer to sort by oldest you can do so and it will be remembered.

Comment: I don't think I can sord by oldest.  My options are "Relevance", "Newest", and etc...

Comment: Yeah you're right... you'd have to scroll to the bottom of the page, except for questions that have more than one page of answers, and one has to click through to the final page (which is annoying). You might want to post this separately as a feature request?

Answer (score 4):

You can sort by newest and then scroll down and navigate to the last page.

[image]